# Binding to paper-dropdown-menu with Aurelia

Tags: drop-down-menu, polymer, aurelia

I am wanting to provide a dynamic set of items to a Polymer `paper-dropdown-menu`.  I can get the dynamic items to show up, but clicking them does nothing.

View:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite pastry">
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" selected.two-way="favPastry" attr-for-selected="value">
    <!-- Begin works when selected -->
    <paper-item value="Croissant">Croissant</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="Donut">Donut</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="Financier">Financier</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="Madeleine">Madeleine</paper-item>
    <!-- End works when selected -->

    <!-- Begin does not work when selected -->
    <paper-item repeat.for="pastry of pastries" value="${pastry}">${pastry}</paper-item>
    <!-- End does not work when selected -->
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

View-model:

```
pastries = [ "Bear Claw", "Pie" ];
favPastry = "Donut";
```

**How can I provide a dynamic list of items to a `paper-dropdown-menu` in an Aurelia application?**

Answer (score 0):

To create the `paper-item`s out of your array, you'll have to use a `<template is="dom-repeat">` as described here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat